# Why so much problem with IE and Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: URL +'/foo/',
  data: {'pass': pass},
  dataType: "json",
  jsonp:'jsonp_callback',
  success: function(data) {
    if (data["success"] === "false") {
      $("#password").val("");
      $('.error-message').removeClass('hide')
      $('.error-message').addClass('show')
    }
    else {
      var tempUrl="http://10.0.1.101:9000/bar/"
      location.href=tempUrl;
    }
  },
});
return false
```

This is working fine in Mozilla, Chrome, Safari. But Not in IE. What could be the reason. I am returning suucess value from server. If success is True it will redirect to `tempUrl`.
But nothing is happing here in IE. It seems that ajax is not at all working in IE.

Comment: Please specify which version(s) of IE you're testing against. (IE sucks, but IE6 sucks a lot more than IE8).

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors?

Comment: IE 7 and i am not seeing any JS error.

Comment: maybe a stupid question but have you refreshed your cache

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. **Please** take a moment to make sure the code you post is readable. The indentation of the code in your question is *all over* the place and in fact you haven't formatted some of it at all. The better your question is, the better the quality and quantity of the answers you'll get. (I've fixed the indentation problems for you.)

Answer (score 4):

You're running into the "dangling comma" problem (the comma after the closing `}` of your `success` parameter). IE doesn't like dangling commas in object literals, it treats them as syntax errors and your script dies. (This isn't an IE bug, it's a reasonable interpretation of the earlier spec; the newest spec specifically allows the comma, though, and this is fixed in IE8.) *Off-topic: IE has a similar, but different, issue with dangling commas in array literals (which is still in IE8).*

More on both isuses [this article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/literal-improvement.html), but basically:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: URL +'/foo/',
  data: {'pass': pass},
  dataType: "json",
  jsonp:'jsonp_callback',
  success: function(data) {
    if (data["success"] === "false") {
      $("#password").val("");
      $('.error-message').removeClass('hide')   // <== Strongly recommend ; here
      $('.error-message').addClass('show')      // <== Another ; here
    }
    else {
      var tempUrl="http://10.0.1.101:9000/bar/" // <== Another ; here
      location.href=tempUrl;
    }
  }, // <== This comma is the problem
});
return false                                    // <== Another ; here
```

See the note near the bottom. Remove the comma and you're fine. Things are improving (as outlined in the linked article above), but for maximum compatibility in the wild, you need to watch this for a while longer.

(The other notes are off-topic, but again, strongly recommend fixing those as well, *never* rely on semicolon insertion.)

Answer (score 0):

You should add semicolons in the end of these lines:

```
$('.error-message').removeClass('hide')
$('.error-message').addClass('show')
var tempUrl="http://10.0.1.101:9000/bar/"
```